# Ifconfig does not show my IP

Tags: command-line, ip, ifconfig

When i'm putting the code on: `ifconfig`

`ifconfig` results in a terminal shows:

```
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr: f8:a9:63:64:3f:1c 
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1 
RX packets: 0 errors:0 dropped: 0 overruns: 0 frame: 0 
TX packets: 0 errors:0 dropped: 0 overruns: 0 carrier: 0 
colisions: 0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Does not show my Itnet addr, bcast and mask!

What's that supposed to mean?

Comment: What does it show?

Comment: It shows: 

eth0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr:  f8:a9:63:64:3f:1c  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets: 0 errors:0 dropped: 0 overruns: 0 frame: 0
          TX packets: 0 errors:0 dropped: 0 overruns:  0 carrier: 0
          colisions: 0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

You see that is missing this lines?

Comment: So it's not seeing your Wi-Fi chip?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add more information.

Answer (score 14):

The interface `eth0` is up, so the underlying device is found. There no IP address associated to this interface.

Assign an ip address manually:

```
$ sudo ifconfig eth0 w.x.y.z
```

Or contact the DHCP server, if it exists, and let it provides an ip address for the interface:

```
$ sudo dhclient -v eth0
```

If something goes wrong, `dhclient` will print error messages. They should be used to troubleshoot.

### ----

If the system just booted, then there could be a missing configuration or a mistake in interfaces configuration.

In order to fix issues of interfaces setting at boot or If you would like to make the settings persistent over the reboot:

- `man interfaces`
- edit `/etc/network/interfaces` file